# RegEx Parser like in Automata Class

Tags: regex, perl, computer-science, theory, automata

It seems that most CS textbooks in Automata theory cover Regular Expressions with the alphabet *Σ = {0, 1}* or *Σ = {a, b}*.

Many students in Automata class had trouble writing RegEx's, is there a parser that accepts something like the following examples? Perl RegEx and similar syntax is too dissimilar to be useful.

Some examples:

```
(0+1)*                  # All words in the language
(0+1)((0+1)(0+1))*      # All words of odd length
0(0+1)*1                # Words starting with 0 and ending with 1
0*+0*10*+0*10*10*       # Has at most two 1's
(0+10)(0+1)*(1+10)      # Begins with 0 or 10 and ends with 1 or 10
(1+011)*                # Every 0 followed by two 1's
```

In the syntax used in this class and several textbooks, a `*` indicates matching 0+ times, and a `+` indicates OR.

Does something out there exist to do this, or should I built my own parser?

Comment: Regex syntax is more closely based on EBNR.

Comment: EBNR? A Google search for this doesn't return anything useful and I've never heard of this.

Comment: EBNF, that is.  Enhanced BNF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look that different from standard regex... the only change you would have to make is to swap `+` with `|` (change `(0+1)` to `(0|1)`).  Apart from that, you would just have to make the resulting regex match the entire line, either by prepending `^` and suffixing `$` or by setting the appropriate option.

Shouldn't be more than a couple lines to wrap the standard regex parser.

Comment: I will look into this. I've added some more examples of what this parser must support -- it might be more complex than you originally thought, but I'm somewhat clueless on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: None of your examples change the ability to use a standard parser.  I updated my answer to adjust for the definition of `+`.